# JSON formatter prototype basic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to include the Object prototype on my code but I have no idea where to start.

Listing in the framework documentation,
[Json Formatter](http://azimi.me/json-formatter/demo/demo.html):

```
 $scope.deep = {a:{b:{c:{d:{e:{}}}}}};
```

This does not include the prototypes:

```
$scope.deep = Object.create({"hi":"test"});
```

Any idea why this is happening? If so, how am I going to code the child properties to show it in the framework?

Comment: Yes, `JSON.format` does not inspect inherited properties. If you want to include `hi`, add a `toJSON` method to the object that returns an object with enumerable own properties.

Comment: why is Object.keys() not including the Object prototype?

Comment: That's just [what it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).